# Can't remove   libreoffice3.5-dict-de   package

Tags: package-management, uninstall, aptitude

I just installed the wrong version of LibreOffice (x86 instead of 64bit). So I tried to remove it but I get this error:

```
> aptitude remove libreoffice3.5-dict-de
Couldn't find package "libreoffice3.5-dict-de".  However, the following
packages contain "libreoffice3.5-dict-de" in their name:
  libreoffice3.5-dict-de 
Couldn't find package "libreoffice3.5-dict-de".  However, the following
packages contain "libreoffice3.5-dict-de" in their name:
  libreoffice3.5-dict-de 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

The same happens when I try to use "Software Management". What's going on?

aptitude: 0.6.4-1ubuntu2
Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo aptitude remove libreoffice3.5-dict-de:i386` as you installed the i386 instead of amd64.